# Shutdown Client via cmd and enter boot menu

Tags: windows, windows-11, lenovo-desktop-computer

I'm trying to enter the boot-menu on my Lenovo P3 Tower, but it boots too fast for me to click the buttons.

I tried to access the boot-menu via cmd, by entering the prompt:

```
shutdown.exe /r /f /fw /t 000
```

The problem I have is:

```
The client doesnt have the required permission. (1314)
```

I'm trying it as an admin.

The shutdown and restart works, but the '/fw' part doesn't.

Does anyone have a clue on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: /fw is used to combine with another shutdown command.  That appears to be why it does not work. Try a simple restart.  That normally slows down the startup so you can manage the buttons.

Comment: I've tried that for the last hour in many different variations, I'm afraid it doesn't :D

Comment: try pressing start, shutdown button, then press and hold shift before clicking restart. This should boot into UEFI troubelshoot menu, from where you should be able to access the UEFI firmware menu and boot from other devices. Another option is to startup the computer, and during boot, turn off the laptop by holding the powerbutton 3 times to enter the same menu.

Comment: As above.  Another thing that has worked for me on my Lenovo desktop is:  Shut down.  Start Up and immediately press F1 repeatedly.  That will normally get you into the boot menu.

Comment: I have tried all methods you have mentioned. And the one where I held shift before clicking restart had a different outcome: 

the device started but it didn't project any screen. I have left it for like 10 minutes but nothing changed. So I shut it down again by holding the power button and back to usual :D

I'm trying to pxe-boot the device so the modified windows 11 of the company can run on the device maybe u guys have a different solution for that?

Comment: It is within reason that the company image will not allow you to get into the boot menu.

Comment: The same problem occurs, when I shutdown the device during boot and turn it off manually. After three times I just get a black screen and nothing happens, even though the device is running. But If I restart it again I just get back to the regular windows log in screen. 

I also get the same issue, when I try to restart the device, via settings > recovery.

Comment: @John but the company image is not yet on the device :D

Comment: when I try to restart the device, via settings > recovery.     ....  I would now suggest hardware tests (Lenovo Diagnostics App on bootable USB) to test hardware, particularly the drive.

Comment: So the shutdown method with shift and tripple shutdown do work, the question is only why you don't see the UEFI menu. Are you using an external monitor that does not support the resolution? Does your computer have more than one outputs for display, and is it now sending video to the other output? Its also likely that the shutdown stuff you tried works, but also results in the blank screen.

Comment: @LPChip I'm trying it on two ThinkStation devices at the same time and both have the same issue. One is connected to an older Fujitsu-B22W-7 via display port. 

The other is connected to a Lenovo L24-i30 via HDMI. 

U are right the resolution could be an issue. But what is the resolution of the UEFI-menu? The setup with the Fujitsu display always used to work with the "smaller" ThinkCentres of Lenovo. 

But definitely thanks for this hint, I'll try it with different displays aswell.

Comment: The other is connected to a Lenovo L24-i30 via HDMI.    ....   I have this here and starting in the boot menu from a cold start is not an issue. I will keep thinking about this.

Comment: Tried it now with a ThinkVision P27-q20, same issue. Display always enters standby mode. Guess No signal?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the only display output? I suspect it is trying to output to good old VGA (SUB-D), or maybe DVI-D. not displayport nor hdmi. Could be a separate connector coming directly from the motherboard even, in case you have a dedicated graphics card too.

Comment: yes, VGA and DVI-D are not available, the only output options are 1x HDMI und 2x DP

Comment: SOLVED!!! i had to connect the display via the mini DP-Ports from the graphic card. I could then see the boot menu. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In elevated CMD try with;
"shutdown /r /o /t 0"
/o is the one that you want.

You can also use Start -> Run -> "MsConfig", go under boot tab and select safeboot(note that this you have to return in order to normally boot later on)

Third option is what LPChip mentioned, hold Shift while you click reset button under Start menu.

Last two options I do not recommend, one is messing around with bcedit.

Or you can "trigger" windows safe mode by preventing its boot 3 times.
During boot, first time windows logo appears you simply click reset button once on your pc case(if you dont have reset, power button wont do, cord has to be taken out instead).
Note that both last 2 "advices" are not recommended unless other stuff fails(additional shocks to mobo and drive if messing around with power cord), nothing terrible should happen, but can!